# Software Center not respondng when installing Steam

Tags: software-installation, freeze, steam

Whenever I try to install Steam from the Software Center, the center goes unresponsive and I have to cancel it. I get no error message other than "Not responding". I have tried installing the Steam Launcher from their website which costs money in the Software Center. But after the installation I can't run it, I get no error message; it just won't start. I am able to install other programs such as Virtual Box from the Software Center though. What to do? I use Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: what ubuntu version are you using? and please use `@username` to reply to someone, for example `@Fischer` I get notified

Answer (score 2):

Try using apt-get in terminal to install steam

`sudo apt-get install steam`

This will install steam launcher which will then download approx. 200 Mb and install Steam

Comment: that didn't work on my xubuntu 14.04 so I answered differently, if that works for him then great, I don't know what's his ubuntu version he has, if not, well my answer will work everyday

Comment: Worked perfectly for my Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: well I started using 14.04 a month ago when it started its beta stage so maybe it wasn't available in the repo back then :)

Comment: Neither of these solutions worked. Most likely because I’m new to Linux. But would it work if i installed Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 0):

On 14.04 you cannot install steam from software center, well, at least on my PC, it complains about dependencies. On 13.10 you can.

Money? What money? Just grab it from [here](http://store.steampowered.com/about/), click on "install now" button, it should download a deb file. Open a terminal and do:

```
sudo dpkg -i steam_latest.deb
```

It should start complaining about dependencies, if not then you're done. Otherwise do:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```